# How to Terminate loop/thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa

Here is part of my program. Loop in findDuplicates starts in background thread after button was pressed. Is there any way to stop/kill thread/loop by pressing another button?

```
- (IBAction)countDups:(id)sender {
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(findDuplicates) withObject:nil];
}

-(void)findDuplicates
{
...
 for(int index=0;index<self.resultList.count;index++)
 { ... }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return from background  thread. create one member variable, initialize it with NO.

```
- (IBAction)countDups:(id)sender {
   mCancel = NO;
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(findDuplicates) withObject:nil];
}

-(IBAction)stop
{
  mCancel = YES; //BOOL member variable;
}

-(void)findDuplicates
{
...
 for(int index=0;index<self.resultList.count;index++)
 { 
   If(mCancel)
   return; // return for thread to end

  ... }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read up in the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html) under **Terminating a Thread**. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` essentially creates a new thread and runs the code on it.